# Arity mismatch for datatable. Works for intellij and doesn't work for maven

Tags: maven, cucumber, gherkin

**Cucumber step:**

```
 When config API Client creates a **multiple** layers to **3** catalogs "**catalog_name**"
      | PAR1 | layer_name1 |
      | PAR2 | layer_name2 |
      | PAR3 | layer_name3 |
```

**Step definition:**

```
@When("^config API Client creates a (multiple|single) layers to (\\d+) catalogs \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void configApiClientPushesMultipleConfig(String layers, int catalogNum, String catalogId, Map<LayerTypeEnum, String> layerTypesAndIds) throws Throwable {
```

....
}

This works perfectly when I run it through intellij and it fails in maven with this error:

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Arity mismatch: Step Definition '...' with pattern [^config API Client creates a (multiple|single) layers to (\d+) catalogs "([^"]*)"$] is declared with 4 parameters. However, the gherkin step has 3 arguments [multiple, 3, catalog_name]. 
Step: When config API Client creates a multiple layers to 3 catalogs "catalog_name"
```

I tried for cucumber jvm version 1.2.0, 1.2.4, 1.2.5

Could you please advice what I'm doing wrong and how I can make it workable for maven
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The number of arguments (4 args ) passed to the public void configApiClientPushesMultipleConfig() differs from the number of arguments in your gherkin step (3). So you expect 4 parameters for your method but you provide in your gherkin step only 3.

Comment: There is datatable which has to be considered as a 4th param

Answer (score 0):

So, in my project I'm using cucable maven plugin for parallel running. Updating this plugin version from 0.0.4 to 0.0.8 fixed the issue.